# What are the typical rules for quitting a paid internship?

Tags: professionalism, internship

I am supposed to begin a paid internship soon but due to personal reasons I must resign. Do I have to wait 2 weeks even if I haven't started?

Answer (score 3):

Contact your employer immediately, and let him know of your situation. Most likely, they won't require the two-week notice from you and they'll offer the internship to the next best candidate on the list.

Answer (score 0):

Well that highly depends on the contract you signed and the legal circumstances in the country you live in.
I had to quit a paid internship last year and the best thing to do is just speaking to them - they will understand your reasons and help you.